# How to move blob from one storage account to another using logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-storage-account

I have a standard logic app where one of the step is to copy files to a different storage account, only connector i found was copy blob it only seems to copy within same storage account.  how do i achieve this ?

Comment: Get the blob content and create a new blob in the desired account, simple.

Comment: Can you provide any approach you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

> How to move blob from one storage account to another using logic app

I have reproduced in my environment and I do agree with @Skin and below are my expected results:

**`Design:`**

[image]

Then after changing:

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

Blob copied to another storage account:

[image]